# Maven cannot found library com.sun.errorhandler.exceptionhandler

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I need to add the com.sun.errorhandler.exceptionhandler library, but Maven cannot find it.

In Maven there is an option to add repositories, which add libraries that are not maven default.

Here is an example of my POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <name>Spring Plugins Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>netbeans-repo</id>
        <name>Netbeans Plugins Repository</name>
        <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This section adds the dependencies below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.woodstock</groupId>
    <artifactId>webui-jsf</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency> ...                               
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency> ...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsfcl</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE65</version>
</dependency> ...
```

Does anyone know which repository I add to be able to add library dependency?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such library. My guess is that you're looking for the class `com.sun.errorhandler.ExceptionHandler` because Google offers some links which contain this string.

That's part of the private part of the Java SDK and you shouldn't use it in your code. I'm guessing that you want to install an `ExceptionHandlerServlet`. Look into the documentation of your web framework (RichFaces, I guess) how to install your own error handler.

I haven't used RichFaces before but [the documentation says](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features-Server-side_errors):

> 5.2.2. Server-side errors
>
> Use the JSF 2 ExceptionHandler class to handle server-side errors such as session expiration.

This might help you getting started: https://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/

Comment: Exact. I am migrating an application with the following structure: JSF1.2, Richfaces 3.3.3, Hibernate 3.3.3. 
I added maven to the project to help me manage the libraries. 
I need to make the application run and then start migrating versions of those libraries. 
I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: If you can't fix it yourself, edit your question to read "Looking to replace com.sun.errorhandler.ExceptionHandler in ???.xml" (replace "???" with the name of the file) and then edit your question what you should use when using RIchFaces 3.3.3. Hibernate and Maven are irrelevant for this; this is a configuration error in JSF/RichFaces.